# Cannot resolve symbol default_web_client_id in Firebase's Android Codelab

Tags: android, firebase, cannot-find-symbol

I am trying to learn Firebase, so I went through the Android Codelab. The project they gave me however, had an error:

> Cannot resolve symbol default_web_client_id

And I didn't know how to solve it, since I didn't know the value of `default_web_client_id` or what it is. It is in the `onCreate()` method:
**SigninActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    // Assign fields
    mSignInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);

    // Set click listeners
    mSignInButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Configure Google Sign In
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
}
```

I have no idea what it is, what's its value is, and why is it giving me this error. I haven't changed anything so far except for adding the `google-services.json`. I have added my [SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) and enabled Google in the console.

Comment: you have to register to the Auth 2.0 from developer.google.com. use this: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=_ to generate a Auth 2.0 key

Comment: @M.WaqasPervez I have already added my SHA1 key, is Auth2.0 different?

Comment: Can you make sure that you have this line `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the bottom of your `app/build.gradle`, as documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_the_sdk)?

Comment: ref this : https://chetan-garg36.medium.com/resolve-default-web-client-id-please-a37508e3f88b

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Sometimes there is issue while parsing `google-services.json`. I have reported this issue with to concerned team.

Meanwhile follow below step to fix this issue to get going further -

1) Open `google-services.json` file -> client -> oauth_client -> client_id

2) Copy this client ID and hardcode this `.requestIdToken("your ID")`

It would allow to request "IdToken" via GoogleSignInAccount post successful google login and to authorize your credential with firebase.

**EDIT**

Try deleting and recreating the project and re-importing new `google-service.json`in your Android project

Comment: This is what I see in oauth_client: `"oauth_client": []` there is no ID, and I can't find `client_id` anywhere in the  file either.

Comment: @AbAppletic try adding SHA1 key and re-downloading the config file from firebase console - project setting

Comment: Still nothing. I have added my SHA1

Comment: @AbAppletic if you have just started with the project. try deleting and re-creating a new project -> add android app. This should work. Even if does not work try contacting firebase team.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Deleting the app then remaking it fixed the problem from the beginning, didn't have to hardcode anything.

Comment: What if you have more than 1 client ids? I just looked at my project just now.  There is one for client type 1 and client type 3. What does these mean?

Comment: This isn't quite right. You need to make sure client_type is 3. See my answer.

Comment: got error ApiException: 12500: at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus

Answer (score 20):

A more generic solution would be to add the `google-services.json` into the app's root directory.
And add

`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services`  at the end of `build.gradle` file.

**Explanation**

When the app builds the key value pair strings from `google-services.json` config file are then placed into the `values.xml` file to make them globally available for use from anywhere in your code. This saves us from hard coding the client_id in your code.

**Note**

Do not add the `default_web_client_id` with `client_id` as its value in the `strings.xml` in order to avoid the error of duplication, `Error: Duplicate resources`later on when you run your code.

Comment: build worked after making this update and then running invalidate cache & restart.  much nicer than having to edit the .json file - thanks

Comment: Did not work in my case. I am using Android Studio 4.1

Answer (score 12):

After a time searching the "smart" fix without insert directly the `client_id`, following this answer from [FirebaseUI project](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1381#issuecomment-478288501) I just need to add the next line in `app/build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.2'
```

Comment: That helps to resolve an error during build. However, yet it does not automatically put ID from json file to values.xml... So it works but does not login :(

Comment: Yes it worked for me, thank you so much and it's better than just insert the `client_id` directly

Comment: still there. in 2023. Google is amazing in hardliving.

Answer (score 12):

1. `google-services.json` in ./app/ folder
2. Add in project-level `build.gradle` the following:

```
    buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
    }
```

3. In app-level `build.gradle`, apply the plugin:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is the annoying thing I found. Upgrading it from `4.3.5` to anything higher than that makes Android Studio unable to detect the generated values.xml file.

Comment: Same com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10 not working ,so I implemented 4.3.5

Comment: Damn, this really works. My build didn't fail by that error so I was ignoring it all along thinking its a glitch somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently `R.string.default_web_client_id` is generated from the IDE build

*I had assumed we are supposed to manually add it - time consuming mistake*

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin

> The google-services plugin has two main functions: 1) Process the
>   google-services.json file and produce Android resources that can be
>   used in your application's code.

~~~~

> The main result of the JSON processing is to produce two XML files
>   which you can reference as Android resources in your Java code.

And so - after successful build, if you search the IDE for string `default_web_client_id` , you will see one result is **values.xml** under the /generated folder, and there it has the values for your firebase config, like the example below.

*Actually seeing that file, helped to clarify things here*

```
<resources>
    <string name="default_web_client_id" translatable="false">123.apps.googleusercontent.com</string>
    <string name="firebase_database_url" translatable="false">https://123.firebaseio.com</string>
    <string name="gcm_defaultSenderId" translatable="false">123</string>
    <string name="google_api_key" translatable="false">123</string>
    <string name="google_app_id" translatable="false">123</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: This is solution to my problem, I just did rebuild of project & it worked.

Answer (score 4):

**The main issue with this right now for me was to make sure to download the json file from the same location.  If the initial one came from the firebase console do not use the api console to get the file, and vise versa. The files are not the same **

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just tried to google download json file from API, but for now all the links refer to download page of Firebase :(

Comment: sorry to hear that, but it kind of depends where the original file came from.   if the project was originally a firebase project then use that file.  if the project came from the api console download and use that file.  Don't mix them.  At the time of this post that was true.  Unfortunately it is a moving target.

Comment: Well anyway for now I hardcoded the web id, at least it works, even though hardcoded

Comment: also sent an issue to firebase, they didn't respond at all - so in the future I would move all the backend from firebase to something more reliable

Answer (score 3):

I already have `google-services.json` downloaded and parsed, but still  it doesn't find the string.

I noticed that my `oauth_client` had a key with client_type of `1` and that's all. In the Google API console, I only had an Android key.

So, you need to go to the API console and generate a `Web Server` key. Then, download your google-services.json again, and you'll have a `oauth_client` with a type of 3.

Now, the plugin will generate a string called default_web_client_id.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem or similar,

Make sure that in your google-services.json you have:

```
...    
"client": [
        ...
          "oauth_client": [
            ...
            {
              "client_id": "YOUR WEB CLIENT ID",
              "client_type": 3
            }     
...
```

For some reason the file downloaded from firebase console doesn't include it.

After adding the entry in the google-services.json file, everything started working as expected.

[google-services-plugin documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the Dexto's Answer I would like to mention one more thing
In the JSON file you will get two kind of client id

One Which is having **client_type** value 1 and Another with the **client_type** value 3 
Make sure you specified the **client_id** of **client_type** which has value of 3

Answer (score 2):

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```

has a problem. instead use:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

Download your newest `google-services.json`. List of `client_id` is present for **OAuth 2.0 client IDs** in your [Google Cloud Credentials](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials).

Then check whether it contains `client_id` with `"client_type" : 3` or not. If not, you need to create a new one:

1. Open the [Credentials](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) page in the API Console.
2. Click **Create credentials** -> **OAuth cliend ID**. Then chose type **Web application**.
3. Wait 2-3 minutes, refresh [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/) & download your `google-services.json` again. It should contain `client_id` with `"client_type" : 3` now.

Clean & rebuild your project to apply new API config.

---

The `client_id` with `"client_type" : 3` is usually inside `oauth_client` tag, not `services` or `other_platform_oauth_client`.

If you fall to this case & cannot build the project, try copy your `client_id` to `oauth_client` tag and rebuild again.

```
"client": [
        ...
        "oauth_client": [
            ...
            {
              "client_id": "YOUR WEB CLIENT ID",
              "client_type": 3
            }
        ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

for my case:
The lib was old so I go get the last lib at: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui

put in dependency:
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:7.2.0'

along with what currently there

// Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.7.0')

// When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'

and it is fixed

Comment: Not fixed for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading your `.json` file again after changing the configuration in the Firebase console. Use this newer configuration file, not the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed after using this link to create my backend id to Google API.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#get_your_backend_servers_oauth_20_client_id

- 1- Open the Credentials page in the API Console.
- 2- The Web application type client ID is your backend server's OAuth 2.0 client ID.

After this, you can re-download your json file and android studio will automatically matching your string id.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late to answer but hope this will help someone in the future.

To access there is no need to hard code default_web_client_id in app.

To access **default_web_client_id** in Android App from google-services.json, we have to add SHA1 key under FireBase project Settings.

Go to Firebase Console > Open Project > Select App > Add Fingerprint.

After this copy generated google-services.json to project.

After this you will see the difference in json file as below:

Before :

```
"oauth_client": []
```

After :

```
"oauth_client": [
    {
      "client_id": "23........4-asdj...........................asda.googleusercontent.com",
      "client_type": 1,
      "android_info": {
        "package_name": "com.abc.xyz",
        "certificate_hash": "asjhdashhs"
      }
    },.....
```

This will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Generic solution for this is to apply google play services plugin at the end of build.gradle like this

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'



    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    // For Common Dimension
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.5'
    // Retrofit and Gson
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.6.1'
    // Rx Java and Dagger
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'

    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.24'
    compileOnly 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    compileOnly 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
    // Glide Image Loading
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:30.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:30.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:30.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    /*Jsoup*/
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.1'

    /*Firebase*/
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.2'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:6.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'

    /*location and google map*/
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.1.0'

    /*Circle Image View*/
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:2.0.4'
    implementation "com.android.support:design:30.0.0"
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.15.3'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case I forgot to add

```
id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

to the plugin of build.gradle(:app)

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue, make sure "google-services.json" is in your app directory. Then simply rebuild the project from "**Build -> Rebuild Project**"

Since the string resource "default_web_client_id" is auto-generated, it will be resolved once you rebuild the project

Answer (score 0):

Use BOM to use the compatible version of firebase.

In your module (app-level) Gradle file:

```
dependencies {
  // ...

  // Import the Firebase BoM
  implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.3.0')

  // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies

  // Declare the dependency for the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

  // Declare the dependencies for any other desired Firebase products
  // For example, declare the dependencies for Firebase Authentication and Cloud Firestore
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
}
```

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?authuser=0&hl=en#add-sdks

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is just Rebuild the project and that works for me.

Yes I have checked before doing that my google-services.json file is on the proper place and it is having client_type = 3 as key and client_id = "Your Client Id" as well.

Consider here "Your Client Id" = Your app's client ID which you will get from the firebase.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, google-services.json file "client" -> "oauth_client" -> has no details.

```
"oauth_client": [
    { 
    }
```

],

Therefore I download google-services.json file from my Firebase Project Settings and replace the file in my project.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Update your project level build.gradle file with the following code:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}}
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com"}  
}}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir }
```

More Details:[answerdone.com](http://answerdone.com)

Answer (score -1):

For me the problem was because I was using minSdkVersion 15, updating to 16 has solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

I have searched for it whole day, I already have pasted that json file inside App and rebuild many times, but the android studio still marks it as error in ide.

Solution: just run the project, ignore the error, it will work, it is an IDE bug.

Answer (score -2):

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.0')

implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.2'
```

Put these lines into `build.gradle(projectName)`