# Google Sign in error after Firebase owner changed

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

The app was working fine till the ownership in Firebase has changed from my account to my team lead. Now Google Sign in won't work and this is the error that occured.

Google sign in failed
    com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 7:

I have tried searching a lot of questions but couldn't find any such situations. Please help! I have tried downloading the new Google-Services.json file after the ownership changed. Initially, after the ownership change, there was a compile error for the line
    .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
saying, cannot resolve symbol : default_web_client_id

After some initial search, I've added the Gradle file -

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'
```

which removed that error but from then on Google Sign in didn't work.

This is the part of build.gradle file

```
// Firebase Auth
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
// Google play services
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
```

It also has
     apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: Did you add SHA fingerprint to your new firebase account?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, Yes I have added it long ago and it was working well till this ownership change. Will a new SHA1 be generated due to this change?

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the word 'new'. So you are saying that the owner's Firebase account should have the SHA1 fingerprint. Thanks, I'll check and let you know.

Comment: So,does that worked or not?

Comment: Hi, apologies for the late reply! Turns out this error occurred after the Android Studio update as mentioned in this recent StackOverflow question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54323451/cannot-resolve-symbol-default-web-client-id-googlesigninoptions-android-firebase